# Смена кодировки java

Tags: java, xml

Подскажите пожалуйста, считываю построчно xml файл, но местами в нем неверная кодировка. Приходят значения типа "&#1090 ;&#1086 ;&#1088 ;"

Как с помощью java можно корректно отобразить текст?

Comment: Не думая, что это сбой кодировки, это же html-коды, и Вам надо найти способ преобразовать их в символы

Comment: Покажите, как вы работаете с этим xml. Стандартные xml-парсеры сами преобразуют сущности (entities) в правильные символы.

Comment: Не нужно читать xml-файлы «построчно», используйте нормальные xml-парсеры и они сами всё раскодируют как надо

Answer (score 0):

Это *скорее всего* так в файле "зашифрована" кириллица. Т.е. это, как уже писал Agzam4, html-коды. Они представляют из себя знаки `&#` `цифры` и `;`. `Цифры` - это значение из таблицы символов Unicode. Т.е. по сути, из файла нужно найти все эти HTML коды и перевести в символы Unicode.

Если не использовать сторонние библиотеки, то можно написать что-то вроде такого:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "Рубрика \"Мои любимые буквы\". Первая буква это \"&#1090;\", " +
            "вторая \"&#1086;\" ну и последняя, вообще так себе буква но ладно - \"&#1088;\".";

    System.out.println(replaceHtmlToUtf(text));
}

//заменяем все html коды на utf
public static String replaceHtmlToUtf(String text) {
    //задаём ___шаблон___ подстроки, которую будем искать в тексте
    //Шаблон &#\\d{4}; будет соответствовать подстроке &#4цифры;
    //Примеры: &#1090; &#1000; &#9990; &#1234; &#1212; и т.д.
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("&#\\d{4};");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    //Если в тексте есть совпадения с подстрокой, то find вернёт true
    while (matcher.find()) {
        //А group вернёт подстроку, совпавшую с шаблоном
        String sub = matcher.group();
        //Отправляем в метод, который переведёт html код (его содержит sub) 
        //в символ юникода
        char utfChar = htmlToUtf(sub);
        //заменяем найденую подстроку(ки) на символ, который вернул метод
        text = text.replace(sub, String.valueOf(utfChar));
    }

    return text;
}

//Достаём из &#число; число, парсим (перводим в int) и затем переводим в уже символ (char)
//этот char возвращаем как результат
public static char htmlToUtf(String htmlChar) {
    return (char) Integer.parseInt(htmlChar.substring(2, 6));
}
```

На выходе получаем:

`Рубрика "Мои любимые буквы". Первая буква это "т", вторая "о" ну и последняя, вообще так себе буква но ладно - "р".`

**Если у вас в файле подстроки именно такого формата  `"&#1090 ;&#1086 ;&#1088 ;"` (с пробелом после цифр), то шаблон нужно поменять на `"&#\\d{4}\\s;"`**

*Если вдруг эти подстроки (&#1090 ;&#1086 ;&#1088 ;) не символы юникода, то меняя логику метода htmlToUtf можно переводить их в те символы, которые таким образом зашифрованы*